# PHP in CSS - "If page is in this directory, echo this"

Tags: php, css, directory

I have several sites on the same hosting package. They’re all in different directories. ( i.e. “htdocs/site1”). I want to be able to have them all share one CSS file.

I was wondering if there is a way to change the color of certain elements based on which directory the site is in.

Ideally I would like to be able to define what directory the page is in and what color to use for each directory. Then in my CSS do something like:

`.button { color: <?php echo $color ?> ;}`

to each element that gets a color change.

Is this possible and if so, how do I go about setting this up?

thank you

Comment: Give us an example of what your URL looks like. Are you using subdomains/subdirectories or virtual hosts?

Comment: The url will look like a normal url. 
"www.website.com" will be hosted at "htdocs/site1"

Answer (score 9):

You could add different classes to your body tag depending on the directory:

```
<body class="<?php echo $dir; ?>">
```

where the `$dir` variable is given a different value (let's say `$dir = 'site1'`,...) for each directory...

... And then have something like:

```
.site1 #button { /*styles*/ }
.site2 #button { /*styles*/ }
.site3 #button { /*styles*/ }
```

in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a CSS class to the body tag of the HTML document to determine the site. In PHP you would have to find a way to write the correct site into to the document. Do you use some kind of global template?

Just to give you an idea:

PHP:

```
<?php
  // some code

  // some logic to determine which site you are on - let's say ...
  $site = 'SITE1';
?><body class="<?php echo $site; ?>"><?php
  // more code
?>
```

CSS:

```
body.SITE1 #button { color: #ff0000; }
body.SITE2 #button { color: #0000ff; }
body.SITE2 #button { color: #123456; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically generate the css file using php, where you'd have

```
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'www.site1.com':
        $color = '#ff0000';
        break;
     case 'www.site2.com':
        $color = '...';
        break;
     ...
     default:
        $color = '...';
?>
.someclass { color : <?php echo $color ?>; }
```

This is somewhat inefficient, however. You'd be building a css file just to change a single color each time. Better way is to simply embed the color change in the page's header as an in-line style. That way you don't have to mess with making your server parse CSS files as if they were PHP scripts, and you can put the site-specific css overrides into that inline style in the site's header.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would suggest you add a class to your html tag:

```
<html class="site1">
```

And within your CSS, define your css:

```
.site1 * .button1{ background:#f00;}
.site2 * .button1{ background:#f0f;}
.site3 * .button1{ background:#ff0;}
```

You can find some more information on this subject [here](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/generating_dynamic_css_with_php/) for a PHP approach.